# AWS E2 instances webserver replies AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have an EC2 instance running at AWS with some standard webpages. Since a few days the server replies with "AWS!" instead of delivering the index.page. Checking the source code of this page:

```
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="http://gc.kis.v2.scr.kaspersky-labs.com/XXXXX/main.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>AWS!</body></html>
```

On this instance Kaspersky is not installed. I didnt found any hints on Google so far - maybe someone has made a similiar experience and give me a hint why my index-page is not shown anymore (the code was not changed). Maybe AWS has undergone a change?
Any hint is very appreciated.

Comment: Unless your DNS has changed and is now pointing to a different server, I'd say your server has been compromised.  Amazon would not be changing your web page.

Comment: Check the EC2 console to confirm the Public IP address of the instance. Open your web browser and point it to that IP address. Does it still show that web page?

Comment: Thank you John, stupid me, the IP was not correct in the DNS. Seems the server rebooted and got a new IP. Fixed! Should have seen this - but sometimes.... you need someone bumping you into the wall :) Have a nice weekend.

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed, stdunbar & John pointed into the right direction. DNS entry was wrong.